# How to generate result from - Firestore complex query with multiple .where option along with '=' or '!=' included?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have my Firestore data with below format;

```
Collection: 'DataList'

Document : Autogenerated

Collection:

UserId : 3793
PassMarks: 40
Duration: 60
ObtainedMarks: 45

UserId : 3794
PassMarks: 40
Duration: 60
ObtainedMarks: 35

UserId : 3795
PassMarks: 40
Duration: 60
ObtainedMarks: 70
```

(similar multiple items in a list)

Working query = `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('DataList').where('UserId', is NotEqualTo: 3793).snapshots();`

I want to sort/filter list with below options;

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('DataList')
.where('UserId', is NotEqualTo: 3793)
.where('ObtainedMarks', isGreatedThanOrEqualTo: 'PassMarks)
.orderBy('ObtainedMarks', decending: true)
.snapshots();
```

(**This query will generate error, and written only for better understanding of what i was looking for.**)

I know complex queries could be done referring same field only and if there is '`=`' or '`!=`' is used than we couldn't merge with other queries.

Can anyone kindly advise me alternative way to obtain above result in Flutter.

As I using above $result in a ListView Builder, so I would need in above (`.snapshot()`) but not in (`.map()`) for the simplicity to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the problem you're running into is that you're trying to do a not equal on `UserId` **and** a `>=` on `ObtainedMarks`. That is not possible, as the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#limitations) explains:

> In a compound query, range (`<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`) and not equals (`!=`, `not-in`) comparisons must all filter on the same field.

Your options are:

- Remove the filter in `UserId` from the query, and skip the user's document from the results in your application code. You will be reading too many documents here, but given that you're skipping only one user it may not be a lot of extra documents.
- Add a field `hasPassingMarks` where you capture whether the user's marks are passing, and then perform an equality check (`==`) on that. Unlikely range operations, you *can* have equality checks on different fields.

Comment: Thank you for the idea !

I re-designed my data structure as per your advise (* 2) and added a new field but instead of giving fixed value - I set null to that added new field value. 

Above data structure was demo (not my actual data structure) - hence, i would need this new value check field to be dynamic and shall remain null until conditions are met. 

Now i encounter another issue, in order to write data to that field i am unable to get the Autogenerated Document ID in order to overwrite the null value field assessing certain conditions referring other field values in there.

Comment: If you encountered a new issue, please post a new question with the [minimal, complete code that reproduces that issue](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If the information in my answer allowed you to progress past your initial problem, consider accepting the answer by clicking the ✔ to the left of it, or upvoting it (you may not have enough reputation for that yet).